# Connecting to folder on remote machine using SSH-key - Ubuntu-flavor with suitable file-manager?

Tags: ssh, filemanager, remote-access, sftp

OK, this may come-out as newbie-question and a shot in the dark, but here goes...

I would like an easy way to connect to a folder on a remote computer (a VPS I run), ideally through a folder/connection in the file-manager of my distro.  I would prefer not to use password (although in a pinch I suppose a stored password would work), so ideally it should use a SSH-key, PGP-certificate or something similar.  I can access the VPS via ssh/sftp (prefered) or ftp (in a pinch).

So I'm after a **file-manager** that allows me to create a link to a remote machine, in some way specifying what key/certificate to use.  I'll use that as basis to choose a Desktop Environment, and pick whatever Ubuntu-flavor matches.  I'll be installing it in VirtualBox under Windows anyway, so anything else doesn't really matter...

I would prefer a file-manager with dialogues that let me just fill-in the key/certificate along with the rest of the information.  However, if some obscure URL or run-script is needed, I'm game (though an example would be good).

If there are other, simpler or better way to accomplish something like this, that would also be of interest...

So, what would be the best file-manager and distro for something like this?

Comment: A file manager in Ubuntu has that option. I am not sure if it is the best or second best. It is also not clear what you have already.

Comment: @mikewhatever Which file-manager, which distro?  This will be a new install of one of the Ubuntu-flavours anyway, so I'll just pick the one with the desktop-environment that uses that file-manager.